# Synchronise animation with top of a keyboard with accessory view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a `UITextField` which has an accessory view. I also have another view which resides at the bottom of the screen. I want this view to animate up as the keyboard shows, which I have done plenty of times by utilizing the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`. However, this time it is a little special since I want the bottom view to follow the top of the keyboard and not the top of the accessory view.

Obviously I have tried this solution:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardAnimationDuration delay:0 options:keyboardAnimationCurve animations:^{
        viewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - accessoryViewHeight;
        [self.overviewViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

(`keyboardAnimationDuration`, `keyboardAnimationCurve` and `keyboardHeight` all come from the `userInfo` dictionary of the keyboard notification)

This solution gives me the correct end position of the bottom view, but the animation is slightly off since the keyboard (including the accessory view) has to traverse a longer distance in the same duration (to the top of the accessory view instead of to the top of the keyboard).

I have considered calculating a relative animation duration for my bottom view like this:

```
keyboardToAccessoryRatio = (keyboardHeight - accessoryViewHeight) / keyboardHeight
relativeDuration = keyboardAnimationDuration * keyboardToAccessoryRatio
```

And then have the animation start with a delay of `keyboardAnimationDuration - relativeDuration`. However, this would only work nicely if the keyboard was using the `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` curve, but it is, in fact, using `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`.

So any other suggestions?

PS. I cannot simply add my button view to the accessory view as they are actually in separate view controllers. The animation is done as a part of a custom transition within a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` class.

Comment: As I understand, you can give some delay to animation like 0.5 or 1 and look If it fits.

Comment: It wouldn't fit, even with careful calculations, due to the animation curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up and added the accessory view as a regular view which I made follow the keyboard.